# Offset Calculation is incorrect based on VirutalAddress Property in PE Section Header

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, offset, ghidra

I have created a simple .exe file with flat assembler which is actually doing nothing but just having one instruction

```
format pe64
use64
section '.text' code executable readable
mov eax, 20
```

After created i opened the executable in Ghidra which detected the Language automatically as **PE -> x86:LE:64:default:windows** which seems OK for me.

Now the very first Address is **00400000** which seems also fine based on the PE Format from MSDN (default ImageBase).

When I now go down to the VirtualAddress property which should give me the Location of the Entry Function relative to the ImageBase, Ghidra shows the following 4 Bytes: **00 10 00 00**

Now, maybe I do the math incorrect but shouldn't the Offset calculation then be: 0x400000 + 0x100000 which is **0x500000** ?

Well this Offset is not in my Image. When I go to the EntryPoint (main function) in Ghidra, it is at Offset **0x401000**.

So is my math wrong ? If I remove 1 Byte from the VirtualAddress property it is exactly that location but then it would be 3 Bytes only but the PE Format says the property is 4 Bytes.

Comment: The bytes are in little endian. `00 10 00 00` is `0x00001000`.

Comment: Ahh yeah the endianess... Thanks a lot :)